# How to Run an Exclusive SPLIT in PIG?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm wondering: since the default behavior of the SPLIT relational operator in PIG is to split relations non-exclusively (i.e. if a row fits conditions for 2 or more relations, it will be put into all of them), is there a way to split exclusively instead? What I mean, is I'd like to run a SPLIT statement that would put a row into the first relation whose condition(s) it fits, and then puts it in no other relation, even if it fits a later specified conditions relations.

An example under a normal split:

A=

```
<1, 2, 3>
<4, 2, 1>
<8, 3, 4>
<4, 3, 3>
<7, 2, 5>
<8, 4, 3>
```

then

```
SPLIT A INTO X IF $0 < 7, Y IF ($0 > 2 AND $0<> 7);
```

Gives:

X =

```
<1, 2, 3>
<4, 2, 1>
<4, 3, 3>
```

and

Y =

```
<4, 2, 1>
<8, 3, 4>
<4, 3, 3>
<8, 4, 3>
```

In this case <4,2,1> and <4,3,3> go in both relations. I'd like each to go only into the first relation (A) whose conditions they fit.

NOTE: I know I can do this in two steps by first splitting the first condition off along with it's complement and then splitting the second condition off only the complement, but I'm hoping for a one step solution (or one that at least scales better to many splits) if one exists.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible in the syntax. You will likely have to do `Y IF (NOT $0 < 7) AND ($0 > 2 AND $0<> 7);`.